# What hardware would be good to invest in for a hobbyist?

Tags: ros, hardware, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I have been getting a little into ros now and would like to try and make a robot with some added hardware to it.

I have different things laying around, like arduino's, raspberry pi, motors, h-bridges, joysticks, gps module, kinect sensor etc.

I see some project using the razor 9 dof sensor board and was going to order it. but now I would like to know what different things would be good to purchase more for making a robot base that has ros packages to support it.?
Just like an outdoor rover platform. I will use some wheelchair motors and thinking about buying two of these encoders:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/OMRON-Rotary-Encoder-E6B2-CWZ6C-2000P-R-with-Couplings-5-24v-12v-dc-/331739573483?hash=item4d3d382ceb:g:TPoAAOSwhkRWe8Tg

I don't have a lot of money and would like to not use more than $500, at max $800 in a few months.. so no expensive laser scanners

It would also be preferred if there was a tutorial to follow along or a project that has been described.
at best I think the jetson hack site has some good information and wondering if I should acquire some of the same things.

What are some  good hardware to acquire?

And another question:
If I was to order the razor 9dof from sparkfun the sen14001 version:
**https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14001**
would it be compatible with the ros package even though at the github page it says:
9 Degree of Measurement Attitude and Heading Reference System for Sparkfun 9DOF Razor IMU (SEN-10125 and SEN-10736) and SparkFun 9DOF Sensor Stick (SEN-10183, SEN-10321 and SEN-10724)
https://github.com/Razor-AHRS/razor-9dof-ahrs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258797/what-hardware-would-be-good-to-invest-in-for-a-hobbyist?/) by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-07**:
Good hardware is more fun because you send less time troubleshooting your hardware and more time playing with robots; I'd advise that you spend a little more on good hardware, even if that means having fewer sensors or motors. (also note that price isn't always an indicator of quality)

**Comment by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) on 2017-04-07**:
Thanks ahendrix.
I'll take this advice till me. Also because I've dealt with this pain before, and should acknowledge not to go though it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone then answer if the new razor 9dof sensor module sen14001 version will work with the currently ros packages?

---

Originally posted by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) with karma: 61 on 2017-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-09**:
I know Sparkfun is continuously updating their products and releasing replacement part numbers, and usually the software is compatible even if the hardware is a little different. In this case I don't see the SEN-14001 as replacing the previous Razor 9dof, so it's less clear.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-09**:
The new version could support the same serial protocol as the old Razor, or they may have changed the firmware somehow. I'd look for comments or documentation about the protocol to see if you can confirm that it's the same, or just contact their support team and ask.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-04-09**:
The ros package has some changes for the arduino code, so I vote for not compatible.